# Secure java card access in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, smartcard

Is there any smart card accessing api for windows phone 8 like "openmobileapi" for android and "jsr177 satsa api" for j2me?

As windows phone 7 devices are not having external memory card support , i am looking only for windows phone 8

Answer (score 0):

There is something in place through the Wallet and [SecureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.secureelement%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) APIs which allows you to access the UICC. This requires some privileges. This was developed in the context of NFC payment, and may require a specific SIM. Probably more APIs will emerge in the next release of Windows Phone 8.